# android cursorloader with db from different activity

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-cursorloader

I access a **db in an activity that is used in a different activity**. However when i use `getContentResolver.update()` on the db it won't update in my CursorLoader although it accesses the same db (it's the **same queryUri**). It shows me the updated value when i dump a query to the db, however the CursorLoader won't.

Here is my onCreateLoader method:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri queryUri;
    if(id == ID_LOADER_PORTFOLIO) {
        String[] projection = null;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArguments = null;
        queryUri = MainFeedContract.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(this,
                queryUri,
                MainActivity.COLUMN_NAMES,
                selection,
                selectionArguments,
                null);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and this is my call to update the db in the **same activity**:

```
portfolioBuilder
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Apply",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        EditText et_newValue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_portfolio);
                        Double value = Double.valueOf(et_newValue.getText().toString());
                        String selectedSpinnerCurrency = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("units",value);
                        getContentResolver().update(MainFeedContract.CONTENT_URI, cv, "name=?", new String[]{selectedSpinnerCurrency});
                        Log.d("QUERY", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(getContentResolver().query(MainFeedContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)));

                    }
                });
```

Am i making a mistake when trying to update the db? :/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register a ContentObserver

Call this method in onResume()

```
 public void registerDataObserver() {
    try {
        getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MainFeedContract.CONTENT_URI, true, new DataObserver(new Handler()));
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
    }

}
```

DataObserver class

```
class DataObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public DataObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
         getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

    }
}
```